# Set a stop point for counter in while loop java

Tags: java, arrays, counter

I wrote a method in java that takes an array of ints as argument & retuns true if that array contains three consecutive adjacent numbers. Example 4, 5, 6, or 23, 24, 25. My method works with but with one exception.

The problem is i counter increases more than array index. The index will be either greater than or equal to the size of the array and throw IndexOutOfBounds error. 
My question is how to increase i until i reach to i < array.length not more.

P.S I do not want to use For loop instead of while method in this method!

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] b = {16, 11, 12, 6, 2, 9, 18, 11};
        System.out.println(threeConsecutive(b));

    }
    public static boolean threeConsecutive(int[] a){
        boolean done = false;
        boolean result = true;
        int n = a.length; 
        int i = 0;

        while (!done && i < n){
            if (a[i] + 1 == a[i+1] && a[i] + 2 == a[i+2]) {
                done = true;
                result = true;
                }
            else{
                done = false;
                result = false;
                }
            i++;

        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized. That used to be an option.

Answer (score 1):

> how to increase `i` until `i` reach to `i < array.length` not more.

The `i < n` is already doing that. However, what you actually want is `i+2 < n` because you do `a[i+2]`.

Simplified code:

```
for (int i=0; i+2<n; ++i) {
    if (a[i]+1 == a[i+1] && a[i]+2 == a[i+2]) {
       return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is i exceeds the maximum length of the array.

```
public static boolean threeConsecutive(int[] a){
 boolean done = false;
 boolean result = true;
 int n = a.length; 
 int i = 0;

 while (!done && i < (n-2)){
    if (a[i] + 1 == a[i+1] && a[i] + 2 == a[i+2]) {
        done = true;
        result = true;
        }
    else{
        done = false;
        result = false;
        }
    i++;

 }
 return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're having problems with accessing elements outside of the array. So if i= 7 and n= 8, then your trying to reach i=9 in the a[i+2] part.

The thing is you don't need to check every element in the array, you can just check up to n-2 indexes.
An easy way to do this is add 2 to i or subtract 2 from n before you go into the loop.

Also you want your while statement to use a logical OR not a logical AND.

It would look something like this...

```
...
i=i+2;
while(!done || i< n){
....
}
```

Comment: Your "fix" changing `&&` to `||` is wrong. If the sequence doesn't exist, `done` will remain false, which means `while (!done || ...)` => `while (!false || ...)` => `while (true || ...)` => `while (true)` => Infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

You are getting indexOutOfBounds Exception. If an array has 6 element the last element has index 5. In your while loop condition statement you are checking whether i is less than n (which is correct) but later on in if condition you add 1 and then 2 to the index. If index is 5 then adding 1 or 2 will throw you out of bounds.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] b = {16, 11, 12, 6, 2, 9, 18, 11};
        System.out.println(threeConsecutive(b));
    }
    public static boolean threeConsecutive(int[] a){
        boolean done = false;
        boolean result = true;
        int n = a.length; 
        int i = 0;

        while (!done && i < n -2){
            if (a[i] + 1 == a[i+1] && a[i] + 2 == a[i+2]) {
                done = true;
                result = true;
                }
            else{
                done = false;
                result = false;
                }
            i++;

        }
        return result;
    }
```